# Why would HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath return the path with incorrect casing?

Tags: asp.net

I have an application in which HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath returns the correct path with the wrong casing.

I am then trying to use this in a String.Replace and it does not find the path in the filename due to casing.

I am aware that I can use Regex.Replace but would prefer not to.

I have this problem only on the production machine even though the folder in question has the same casing in dev.

I have just noticed that Server.MapPath also returns the wrong casing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the problem originated in the site directory being specified with the wrong casing in IIS.  Merely changing the home directory does not help the problem as these values are already set in the metabase and apparently since windows in not case sensitive it does not fix the metabase when you fix it in the GUI.

I ended up removing the site and adding it again since it is not in use yet.  I probably could have changed the directory name completely and changed the location in the GUI just as effectively.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

If you don't care about casing, use .ToUpper or .ToLower, and replace on that.

```
Dim path As String = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath.ToUpper
Dim newpath As String = Replace(path, "fnd", "rplc")
```

If that is not an option try changing the compare method in your replace function.

You didn't specify a language, so I cannot give a specific example.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just normalise both strings to lower case -

```
string newpath = somepath.Replace(s1.ToLower(), s2.ToLower());
```